# How do I get an article's author email programmatically?

Tags: users, 8

I would like to send an email to authors when their content updated. How can I get the email of author(s)?

I think `$to = \Drupal::currentUser()->get('mail');` is not my friend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are talking of *authors*, I take you are referring to users who posted a node. In that case, supposing you have a `$node` variable, you should use the following code.

```php
// Add these two lines on the top of the file containing this code.
use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use \Drupal\user\UserInterface;

/** @var \Drupal\user\UserInterface $user */
$user = $node->getOwner();
$email = $user->getEmail();
```

If you are trying to get the email from the currently logged-in user,  you cannot use `\Drupal::currentUser()->get('mail')` because [`\Drupal::currentUser()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AcurrentUser/8.2.x) returns an object that implements [`\Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Session%21AccountProxyInterface.php/interface/AccountProxyInterface/8.2.x), which doesn't have the `get()` method.

If you want the email used by the currently logged-in user, you need to use the following code.

```php
// Put this line on the top of the file containing this code.
use \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
    
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface $user */
$user = \Drupal::currentUser();
$email = $user->getEmail();
```

If you need a [`User`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/class/User/8.2.x) object for other purposes, you should use the following code.

```php
// Add the following two lines on the top of the file containing the code.
use \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
use \Drupal\user\Entity\User;

/** @var \Drupal\user\Entity\User $user */
$user = User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
// You can access the email address with the following line.
$email = $user->get('mail')->value;
// That is exactly equivalent to the following line, which should be prefered.
$email = $user->getEmail();
// The following line require an object implementing UserInterface,
// not AccountProxyInterface, such as the object returned from  User::load().
$user->block();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$to = \Drupal::currentUser()->getEmail();
```

Works on User entities.